# Appending to a link list C

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to append new values to linked list tail, but for some reason it seems like the values are not getting appended. For new linked list allocation:

```
struct checkPoints *checkPt = *checkPoint;

while (checkPt != NULL) {
    checkPt = checkPt->next;
}
if (checkPt == NULL) {
    checkPt = malloc(sizeof (struct checkPoints));
    scanf("%c %d %d %d %d\n", &checkPt->dropOut, &checkPt->currentPoint, &checkPt->competitor, &checkPt->hour, &checkPt->minute);
}
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't adding your new item to the list (and also lose track of the end of the list when you allocate your new item).  Try

```
struct checkPoints *tail = *checkPoint;

struct checkPoints *newItem = malloc(sizeof (struct checkPoints));
scanf("%c %d %d %d %d\n", &checkPt->dropOut, &checkPt->currentPoint,
                          &checkPt->competitor, &checkPt->hour,
                          &checkPt->minute);
newItem->next = NULL;

if (tail == NULL) {
    *checkPoint = newItem
}
else {
    while (tail->next != NULL) {
        tail = tail->next;
    }
    tail->next = newItem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're off by one.

You loop until `checkPt` is `NULL`, but at that point you've lost track of the *last* element of the list (which was `checkPt` *before* it became `NULL`).

The solution might be to loop until the `next` field is NULL:

```
for( checkPt = *checkPoint;
     checkPt != NULL && checkPt->next != NULL;
     checkPt = checkPt->next)
{
   /* Nothing to do here. */
}

if( checkPt != NULL )
{
  struct checkPoints *np = malloc(sizeof *checkPt->next);
  scanf("%c %d %d %d %d\n", &np->dropOut, &np->currentPoint, &np->competitor, &np->hour, &np->minute);
  np->next = NULL;
  checkPt->next = np;
}
```

Comment: Does your code need an extra test to cope with adding to an empty list?

Answer (score 0):

this

```
while (checkPt != NULL) {
    checkPt = checkPt->next;
}
```

will loop until checkPt is NULL so you are not pointing to last element.

easiest is to have an extra pointer that points to the last element in the list, this makes appending elements more effective instead always looking for that by every append e.g.

```
checkPt = malloc(sizeof (struct checkPoints));
lastitem->next = checkPt;
lastitem = checkPt;
```

Answer (score 0):

your are overwritting the tail node memory.

You need to create a temp node,

checktmp = (struct checkPoints*)malloc(sizeof (struct checkPoints));

then add the temp node to the tail.

checkPt->next = checktmp;

Answer (score 0):

You loop until `checkPt` is **NULL**

you can see this:

> O1 --> O2 --> 03 --> ... --> On --> NULL

so, `checkPt` is null, and when you create object and make `checkPt` point to, no problem.

The problem is: On is not point to checkPt now. it still point to NULL. (it means: point to nothing).

So, you just should trace to **last node** (in this case is `On`), and create new object, and make this lastNode point to.

Here is my example code:

```
struct checkPoints *tailPoint = *checkPoint;

  while (tailPoint->next != NULL) {
    tailPoint = tailPoint->next;
  }
  struct checkPoints *newPoints = malloc(sizeof (struct checkPoints));
  // modify newPoints here
  newPoints->next = NULL; // mark it as last node      
  tail->next = newPoint;  // now, mark you last node point to new node. and new node point to end --> NICE
```

as you see, my code has a simple different point: I trace until `tailPoint->next` is NULL, so i still hold the **last element**, but in your code, nothing. it's a big difference.

As simonce has commented, my code will fail if checkPoint is null: often when nothing in the list, yet. So, here is the modified code:

```
// i'm create newPoint first, because always need new points. this will make the code less redundant.

struct checkPoints *tailPoint = *checkPoint;
struct checkPoints *newPoint = malloc(sizeof (struct checkPoints));
// modified newPoint here
// newPoint always last node, so, it will point to NULL.
newPoint->next = NULL; 

if (checkPoint== NULL) {
    *checkPoint = newItem;  // base on new idea
}
else {
    while (tailPoint->next != NULL) {
        tailPoint = tailPoint->next;
    }
    tailPoint->next = newItem;  // as upper code, add last node to tailPoint.
}
```

You should notice different between two case: assign `newItem` to `checkPoint` (first node of linked list) and `tailPoint` (last node of linked list)
Hope this help :)

Comment: Note that this fails in the case where `tailPoint==NULL`